# How to simulate Azure IoT Hub disconnecting

Tags: c, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

I'm using the paho.mqtt.c library to connect to an Azure IoT Hub. I want to test how my software handles disconnections from the IoT Hub.

How can I simulate the IoT Hub disconnecting the client?

There is no "Stop IoT Hub" button in the Azure Portal -> IoT Hub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are some cases for disconnecting a mqtt device from Azure IoT Hub:

- connecting a mqtt device with the same deviceId
- publishing on the wrong topic, for instance: *abcd*
- Disable a device connection to IoT Hub on the portal
- using the REST API for disable a device, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48344685/azure-iot-hub-device-suspension)